# Efficient processing of Data in Data Lake

Tags: optimization, partitioning, scd, data-lake

I need to efficiently process data in Datalake without using the partition key. Is there any effective methods available, please let me know.

Tried to build method to Update data efficiently in Data Lake using the partition key, but I am unable to achieve it as the partition key data changes periodically. I need to find some other method to efficiently process data in Datalake